# Service listening on 8333 leading to vmware-hostd.exe process (VMWare Server 1.0/Windows)

Tags: vmware-server

Have been using VMWare Server 1.0 (Windows server host) (previously setup by a partner of mine) for quite some time now and decided to dig more into processes / memory management.

I have been using VirtualBox for quite some time now and VMWare Server 1.0 is a step back now but cannot migrate VM's that run there for the moment..

So, one day i decided to run nmap on the machine hosting the VMWare Server.

Among other things output returns:

...
8333/tcp open bitcoin

Running netstat to pinpoint the process ID that listens to 8333 shows that a process ID number that is owned by ...vmware-hostd.exe.

Is this normal?

I know that specific port is used by VMWare Server under linux but Windows

Any previous experience on the matter would be largely appreciated.

Thank you in advance.